# Clojure function throwing arity exception when called from within a map

Tags: clojure

```
(map (fn [x]
    (let [username (or (:f_username x) nil)
          sites_names (SITES-NAMES username)
          x (assoc x :sites sites_names)]
     x)) my-rows)
```

In the code above: SITES-NAMES gives me an arity exception.  However
if I call it (SITES-NAMES "theuser") it works.  Why is this the case
if username evaluates as an example to "theuser".

Comment: There should be no reason (from what's to see here), that this function would behave differently in a let or in its own.  So please provide a full example how to reproduce the error you are seeing.

Comment: What does `my_rows` contain?

Comment: what is the source of `SITES-NAMES`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is happening, but here are a few tips:

1) Make your anonymous function a top-level function, as such:

```
(defn add-site [site-names {:keys [f-username] :as x}]
  (assoc x :sites (get site-names f-username)))
```

Notice how I name the vars, refer to https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide for more info on naming and other neat stuff.

2) Now you can change your call to `map` with

```
(map (partial add-site site-names) my-rows)
```

This lets you play around with the `add-site` function at the REPL like so:

```
user> (add-site {"hector" "www.hector.com"} {:f-username "hector"})
;; => {:f-username "hector", :sites "www.hector.com"}
```

You might want to read this as well: 
https://stuartsierra.com/2015/08/10/clojure-donts-redundant-map